Should RSA Accumulators Be Preferred Over Merkle Trees in zk-Rollups?
Currently, most zk-Rollup projects use Merkle trees to commit data. However, recent advancements in RSA accumulators (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1494, https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1672) suggest they might offer advantages over Merkle trees. Could RSA accumulators provide better efficiency or scalability for zk-Rollups? What are the trade-offs involved in switching to RSA accumulators?

This is a great/interesting question.  Unfortunately I fear it may be out of scope for this forum.

@ruby_newbie thank you for your reply. Which forum shall I post this question?
